# Approximation by Taylor expansion

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion, power-series, approximation

I am working on a heterogeneous network model and have the following expression:
$$1 - \frac{z}{\lambda m} - e^{-z} - z\ln ze^{-z} - z\int_z^\infty \ln(x)e^{-x}dx.$$
where $z, \lambda, m, x$ are real numbers with $z=\lambda m \phi$. For brevity, I could not include the derivation of this expression as it is very long and it takes an entire [journal article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0107267.pdf) to derive. The derivation itself is not important anymore at this point.

In that article I linked, the authors take the limit as $z \to 0$ in the last integral to obtain,
$$ \int_0^\infty \ln(x)e^{-x}dx = -\gamma_E $$
where $\gamma_E$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant. What I do not understand is that they also say that by Taylor expansion, the expression approximates to

$$z\bigg[1-\gamma_E - \frac{1}{\lambda m} - \ln z\bigg].$$

I am confused as to whether they took the limit $z \to 0$ for all instances of $z$ in the expression or only in the integral. I have also tried the Taylor expansions of $e^{-z}$ but I can't progress from there. I would like to know exactly how they derived the previous expression from the first one. Any help or direction will be much appreciated. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's define $f(z) := z\int_z^\infty e^{-x}\ln x \,\mathrm{d}x$. One has then $f'(z) = \int_z^\infty e^{-x}\ln x \,\mathrm{d}x + z\,e^{-z}\ln z$. In consequence, its first-order Taylor expansion is given by
$$
f(z) = f(0) + f'(0)z + \mathcal{O}(z^2) = \gamma z + \mathcal{O}(z^2)
$$
Thus we understand that the authors kept all the sub-quadratic terms; indeed, we get :
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\phi(z) 
   &=& \displaystyle
   1 - \frac{z}{\lambda m} - e^{-z} + z\,e^{-z}\ln z - f(z) \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   1 - \frac{z}{\lambda m} - (1 - z + \mathcal{O}(z^2)) - z\,(1 + \mathcal{O}(z))\ln z - (\gamma z + \mathcal{O}(z^2)) \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \left(1 - \gamma - \frac{1}{\lambda m} - \ln z\right)z + \mathcal{O}(z^2)
\end{array}
$$

Comment: @Abhezhiko was $z^2 \ln z$ incorporated into $\mathcal{O}(z^2)$? Sorry if this is obvious, I just need to confirm.

Comment: @user1178472 It **not** true that $z^2\ln z =  \mathcal{O}(z^2)$ because $\ln z$ is not bounded as $x\to 0$ **or** $x\to\infty$.

Comment: @Somos, can you share what happened to this term instead? Or was it just lost in the approximation?

Comment: You're right, my bad. Actually, the authors used a first-order approximation $e^{-z} \approx 1-z$ for the single exponential and a zeroth-order approximation $e^{-z} \approx 1$ for the other one. I'll correct it.

Comment: @Abezhiko more particularly, I'd like to ask for confirmation on $f'(0)z$. Isn't the integral supposed to be $-\gamma$?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer. They did a first-order Taylor expansion in $z$ within every term that is not a log term.

Details. Since $1- e^{-z} = 1-( 1- z) +\ldots$
the total expression can be approximated by

$1 -\frac{z}{m\lambda} -(1- z) - z\ln z (1 -z) - z\gamma$

$=  -\frac{z}{\lambda m} +z - z\gamma - z\ln z$